# Master data services 2016 data validation

Tags: master-data-services, master-data-management, mds

All modules and attributes are created as per my requirement using Master data services 2016. I am working on data validation.

Requirement is that, we have to display custom message to users while he/she is trying to enter duplicate data in the combination of 3 columns (composite primary key) and should not be inserted into database. I tried using triggers in MDS database.

Suggest me the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add business rule of Must be unique and then select Must be unique in combination with the following attributes. I Think we cannot add custom message.
Message will be shown as Column A,B,C must be unique with combination .....